# Edit ZSH theme for virtualenv name

Tags: themes, zsh, prompt, virtualenv

I use zsh theme `intheloops`. The theme looks like this when no virtual env. is active

```
-- an empty line --
[sourabh@skynet] ~/Code/django_apps/cope (master) ⚡ 
❯
```

and when an env. is active,

```
(env name)
[sourabh@skynet] ~/Code/django_apps/cope (master) ⚡ 
❯
```

Can I make it look like this when some virtualenv is active

```
-- empty line --
(env name) [sourabh@skynet] ~/Code/django_apps/cope (master) ⚡ 
❯
```

**`.zsh-theme` file**

```
local return_status="%{$fg[red]%}%(?..⏎)%{$reset_color%}"

local host_color="green"
if [ -n "$SSH_CLIENT" ]; then
  local host_color="red"
fi

PROMPT='
%{$fg_bold[grey]%}[%{$reset_color%}%{$fg_bold[${host_color}]%}%n@%m%{$reset_color%}%{$fg_bold[grey]%}]%{$reset_color%} %{$fg_bold[blue]%}%10c%{$reset_color%} $(git_prompt_info) $(git_remote_status)
%{$fg_bold[cyan]%}❯%{$reset_color%} '


RPROMPT='${return_status}%{$reset_color%}'

ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_PREFIX="%{$fg[yellow]%}(%{$fg[yellow]%}"
ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_SUFFIX="%{$reset_color%}"
ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_DIRTY="%{$fg[yellow]%}) %{$fg[pink]%}⚡%{$reset_color%}"
ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_CLEAN="%{$fg[grey]%})"
ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_BEHIND_REMOTE="%{$fg_bold[magenta]%}↓%{$reset_color%}"
ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_AHEAD_REMOTE="%{$fg_bold[magenta]%}↑%{$reset_color%}"
ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_DIVERGED_REMOTE="%{$fg_bold[magenta]%}↕%{$reset_color%}"
```

Answer (score 6):

How the prompt is changed is defined in the script `bin/activate` inside the virtual environment directory. This file is created by `virtualenv` from a template. Unfortunatelly, the only way of prompt modification provided by the template is prepending `(env name)` or whatever is set with `--prompt`.

To modify the prompt in the way you want, I'd suggest circumventing the setting of the prompt in `bin/activate` and modify the definition of `PROMPT` in your theme file.

First add the following to your`.zsh-theme` (or `.zshrc`)

```
export VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT=yes

function virtenv_indicator {
    if [[ -z $VIRTUAL_ENV ]] then
        psvar[1]=''
    else
        psvar[1]=${VIRTUAL_ENV##*/}
    fi
}

add-zsh-hook precmd virtenv_indicator
```

and add `%(1V.(%1v).)` in front of the second line of the definition of `PROMPT`. It should then look like this:

```
PROMPT='
%(1V.(%1v).)%{$fg_bold[grey]%}[%{$reset_color%}%{$fg_bold[${host_color}]%}%n@%m%{$reset_color%}%{$fg_bold[grey]%}]%{$reset_color%} %{$fg_bold[blue]%}%10c%{$reset_color%} $(git_prompt_info) $(git_remote_status)
%{$fg_bold[cyan]%}❯%{$reset_color%} '
```

If you want some color you could add `%(1V.%{$fs_bold[yellow]%}(%1v)%{$reset_color%}.)` for example.

**Explanation**:

`virtenv_indicator` will be called each time before the prompt is created. It checks if `$VIRTUAL_ENV` is set and not empty. If so, it sets the first element of the `$psvar` array to `$VIRTUAL_ENV` with everything before and including the last `/` removed (like `basename $VIRTUAL_ENV` but less expensive)

In the definition of `PROMPT` `%(1V.(%1v).)` checks if the first element of `$psvar` is set and not empty (`%(1V.true-text.false-text)`) and adds the content of the this element plus some parentheses (`(%1v)`)

`export VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT=yes` disables any prompt setting by `bin/activate` scripts.

Answer (score 2):

`Oh-my-zsh` now includes a `virtualenv` plugin, so just enable it in the `config`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using [prezto](https://github.com/sorin-ionescu/prezto), you can find instructions on how to display the active virtualenv here: https://github.com/sorin-ionescu/prezto/tree/master/modules/python#theming